# PayPal after subscr_eot, renew subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

1. Subscribed user
2. cancel or subscr_eot (expire)
3. re-click on subscription link to renew.

would it renew the same subscription or would it create new one?

if we create new subscription, should we delete old expired subscription?

**i want to know, how should we handle subscription after it expires.**

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I treat this as a new subscription, and I let PayPal create a new subscription (new profile ID or "subscr_id"). Since my application manages both the user/customer record and the subscription(s), this is a "one-to-many" relationship between one customer and many subscriptions in my database.

Notice that this can leave a time gap between the date of the expiration and the date of the renewal. In my app, the user does not have access to the service during that time gap, since there is no active subscription.

So my approach is:

1. let the original subscription terminate (either cancel or
   expire)
2. on "renew", create a new subscription
3. link both subscriptions to the same person (in our customer records)